# Xcode 14: Does anyone know how to remove the blue tint on lines where changes have been made?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, ide

### Problem

Within the Xcode 14 IDE, I have been facing an annoying issue where the lines I am editing tint blue. I have disabled `Show Source Control changes` within Preferences, yet it does not remove it. I have attached an image to show you what it looks like. I really hope you can help as I am finding the blue tints everywhere in my code very distracting and annoying.

[image: Xcode 14: Lines where changes have been made tint blue]

*Just ignore the code - it's just to show what happens when changes are made in the editor.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a button next to where you can show the canvas, 2 arrows pointing in opposite directions. Try pressing it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case if the icon mentioned in accepted answer is missing, go to `View` in Xcode top navigation bar and click `Show Code Review`.